# What is the main difference between "work under a professor" and "work with a professor"?

Tags: phrase-usage

I am not sure about the main difference between saying "I am working under a professor" and saying "I am working with a professor".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Working under** someone implies supervision by this other person. If you work under Professor X, it means Professor X will direct your studies, your research, etc. and you are not their equal.

**Working with** someone should imply equality between the co-workers.  This being said when *with* is used you have to consider the position of each person and if you are a student and you work **with Professor X on your thesis**, which could also be said,  (I'm using the term with the UK sense, I gather the system is different in the US) then of course there is no equality and you are dependent on Professor X.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working under a professor means you are employed by the same college or university.

But if you are working with a professor then you can even be a freelancer.  For example, suppose you and the professor are working on a book. Then you are not his employee but more of a partner in business as you two are working on the same book.